# How to map object types into int64 in pandas.DataFrame with a large data set

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have data for machine learning study, but I stuck with those string features. I want to map `them(object`) into `number(int64)`.

For example, in feature `workclass`, make a `map(dict)` as `{'private':0,'State-gov':1, etc}`.

So, how can I deal with it in DataFrame, should I write a for loop to find like n different classes in a feature, and do a n-keys map for each object feature?

```
# There are the code about data reading
import pandas as pd

df_trainFeatures = pd.read_csv('data/trainFeatures.csv')
object_features = ['workclass','education','Marital-status',
         'occupation','occupation','relationship','race','sex','native-country']
# list data type
for i in df_trainFeatures:
    print(df_trainFeatures[i].dtype,i)

//Printing
int64 age
object workclass
int64 fnlwgt
object education
int64 education-num
object Marital-status
object occupation
object relationship
object race
object sex
int64 capital-gain
int64 capital-loss
int64 hours-per-week
object native-country
```

Sub-Data frame as follow:

[image: Sub-Data]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pandas.get_dummies(data)
```

It will convert categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables.

or in your case

```
pandas.get_dummies(df_trainFeautres['workclass'])
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it. it works but it also add more features.I find an interesting question which will be better with get_dummies or just map in one feature. I am working, thank you very much!!

Comment: mapping to one feature will be unbalanced. Eg: if you map one category to 1 and other to 2, 2 automatically takes the greater weight. So, get_dummies is a standard way to convert categorical values to machine-readable form. If it helped you can consider accepting the answer.